# Why can't `rescue` catch exception classes other than `StandardError` by default?

Tags: ruby, exception

Why has Ruby been designed to handle only `StandardError` exceptions implicitly by `rescue`? For other exceptions, why should we need to put them explicitly with `rescue`?

```
begin
  #codes here which may generates exceptions
rescue
  #codes to handle some thing which really needed to be done when exceptions there
end
```

Can anyone help me understand its core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the default behavior `rescue StandardError` when you don't give the type explicitly is that you'll typically not want to handle non StandardErrors in your program, at least not without explicitly mentioning them. A couple of typical non-StandardError exceptions are;

```
LoadError
NotImplementedError
SyntaxError
```

Normally, you want to know about missing script files in your program, non implemented methods and syntax errors in your code, and not accidentally handle them/ignore them in your exception code.

You can also (NOT recommended) catch *any* exception using the alternate syntax

```
rescue Exception => e
```

Comment: It seems Ruby' exception has been deigned this way,nothing much technical with that.Okay, anyway `+1` to you also. :)

Comment: Downvoter: Voting not helpful without leaving a comment as to why is not helpful either.

Answer (score 2):

I quote from [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html):

> The chart above shows that most of the subclasses extend a class known
>   as StandardError. These are the "normal" exceptions that typical Ruby
>   programs try to handle. The other exceptions represent lower-level,
>   more serious, or less recoverable conditions, and normal Ruby programs
>   do not typically attempt to handle them.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes! I agree with you. The answer is too functional,where as my expectation was bit different,more technical. :) still I am happy with that. `+1` to you.