# How to make Ruby capture the syntax error in threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to code up a two-threads client using ruby, one thread reads the data from a socket and print it out, the other thread reads local data and send it to remote server. The problem I found is that it looks like Ruby cannot capture errors within a thread, here is an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

Thread.new {
  loop {
    $stdout.puts "hi"
    abc.puts ef
    sleep 1
  }
}


loop {
  sleep 1
}
```

Obviously, outside the thread if I type `abc.puts ef` the code will never run since Ruby will report "undefined variable abc". However if it is within a thread, there is no error report. My question is, how to let Ruby capture errors like this? Or at least, report something is wrong within a thread?

Comment: `SyntaxError` is not raised, but `NameError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Thread::abort_on_exception=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D):

According to [Thread - Exception Handling](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#label-Exception+handling):

> Any thread can raise an exception using the raise instance method,
>   which operates similarly to Kernel#raise.
>
> However, it's important to note that an exception that occurs in any
>   thread except the main thread depends on abort_on_exception. This
>   option is false by default, meaning that any unhandled exception will
>   cause the thread to terminate silently when waited on by either join
>   or value. You can change this default by either abort_on_exception=
>   true or setting $DEBUG to true.
>
> ...

```
Thread::abort_on_exception = true
Thread.new {
  loop {
    $stdout.puts "hi"
    abc.puts ef
    sleep 1
  }
}


loop {
  sleep 1
}
```

=>

```
hi
t.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `abc' for main:Object (NameError)
        from t.rb:3:in `loop'
        from t.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

For syntax error catching, rescue must use explict Exception class
(without this, rescue catch only StandardError) :

```
Thread.new {  
begin
  abc.puts ef
rescue  Exception => e
  puts "error #{e}"
end
}
```

see [Why can't `rescue` catch exception classes other than `StandardError` by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786602/why-cant-rescue-catch-exception-classes-other-than-standarderror-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one possible solution is surround the thread lambda with `begin` `rescue` `end` block:

```
Thread.new {
begin
  abc.puts ef
rescue
  puts error
end
}
```